# Best Testing Framework

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests

We are currently working on a REST full application (Java) that also has some SOAP based endpoints, working for a start-up and not having many experienced QA people(we are in the process of hiring some) around our team. Wanted to know whether there is a test framework that can automatically generate HTML test pages for all our endpoints, also every time we make changes to the services something breaks and we have to perform the entire regression manually (we have a few junior QA members who do this right now). So is there a regression testing tool that can be used to perform the API testing along with the performance and load testing. Please point to some frameworks that are generally used as per industry best practices/standards.

Comment: Did you google anything?

Comment: I have evaluated TestNG as well but wanted a neat solution that can ease the pain of writing a new test framework for our tests. Did google a lot but could not find any tool that came even close to what i was looking for, the reason for this question was to find a tool that automated the process of creating HTML Test Pages from our services so that our manual QA team can use it directly rather than them having to use POSTMAN to manually write their tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please head over to **[gatf](https://github.com/sumeetchhetri/gatf)** and **[test-html-generator-plugin](https://github.com/sumeetchhetri/test-html-generator-plugin)**, these are probably the frameworks that you may be looking for. The test-html-generator plugin is a simple maven plugin that converts all your REST services to HTML Test pages and the best part is that it has in-built authentication support as well, it serves you beautiful HTML pages built on top of bootstrap, you should definitely check it out.

Regarding your question for frameworks that can automate your tests, you need to define what you want to test, if you want to perform Browser based tests then **Selenium** is the best option out there and if you want to perform load tests then you should also look at **Jmeter**. But if you want more then you should definitely give **[gatf](https://github.com/sumeetchhetri/gatf)** a try.

GATF comprises of 2 components the *Test generator* and the *Test Executor*
The test generator is again a maven plugin that is capable of generating gatf test cases for all your REST/SOAP endpoints which can then be directly executed by the Test Executor. Form the homepage,

GATF Acceptance Test executor is data-type agnostic, which means that your testcases can be in any formats like *XML, JSON or plain old CSV*

The GATF Test Executor module provides a consolidated testing tool for,

1. Single Session Test case execution
2. Performance Test case execution
3. Scenario/Workflow based Test case execution
4. Concurrent User Simulation
5. Comparative Test case study against multiple environments
6. Load Testing

It also provides the following,

1. Pie charts for overall test status (Success/Failure reports)
2. Line/Bar charts for overall performance results
3. Detailed test case reports with comprehensive information about a test execution request/response
4. Maven/Executable-Jar test case execution options

The GATF framework provides the option to integrate to multiple data sources for fetching test case data, which include the following,

1. Any SQL compliant database
2. MongoDB
3. Files - CSV/JSON/XML
4. Inline/Value based
5. Custom Provider
6. Random Value Provider

The Framework assumes that you use **Jackson/JAXB** for JSON/XML (un)serialization and the **JAX-RS/JAX-WS/Spring-Controller** specifications for your Service implementations.

I am the creator of the above mentioned frameworks, I had long been researching for similar tools/technologies and in the absence of one i started working on my own frameworks. Would love to hear your feedback if you ever decide to use them :-)

Comment: The test-html-generator plugin is exactly what i was looking for, and is indeed very easy to use. It really saved my day. Have been researching a lot and wasn't able to find a decent solution, but your framework really does what you mentioned. Moreover as we use POSTMAN for manual testing, i also did try creating POSTMAN tests using your gatf framework(btw you did not mention that here :-)). If you could also sort out the documentation, even more people would find it useful, i had a hard time figuring out a lot of things. But thanks a lot, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the detailed set of requirements which you want the framework to help you . There are couple of popular frameworks like

1. SST (selenium-simple-test)
2. Samurai Web Testing Framework
3. TestCafe:Web Testing Framework
4. etc.

   There are many out there you have to pick which is best suited for you. Look in to the features specified and try some trials before you choose one .